# Facet block is not getting display on search page created by view

Tags: 8, search

I am using the Search API module with an Apache SOLR server. On my search page, the search results are rendering properly, but the content type facet block is not getting render in any defined region.

I followed the same steps as mentioned in [Enable facets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31p77ka8Tws).

Is there any version compatibility issue?

I am using the following versions of the dependent modules.

- drupal/search_api 1.14
- drupal/facets 1.4
- drupal/search_api_solr 3.7
- drupal/search_api_autocomplete 1.2

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. There was an issue with context which was overriding block layout property and that's the reason facet block was not rendering on the page.

Summary: If you are using context on the page then block layout property will not work for rendering the block. So need to configure block in the context.